# cut an \insert too long and leave the next parts

Tags: tex-core

My problem is in Plain TeX.

I have made a minimal example to explain it:

```
\newinsert\example
\count\example=1000
\dimen\example=1ex
\insert\example{
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
}
\output={\shipout\box255\unvbox\example}

\end
```

As you can see, the insert is split and put in another page, but I would like the first part of the insert to be used, while the other parts (after the cut) be left, or more to be put in another insert.

It's for answering this question: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/17.

The problematic is this : 
 - an insert is created on the left page.
 - it is too long, so it continues and right page.
 - but when (e)ledpar construct the //, it proceed with this method :
 -* Construct the left page
 -* If the right page is full, clear page to go to the right page.

As you can see, the insert declare on the left page can't be continued on what user expected to be the right page : it continues on the right page, and after that, the "what user expected to be the right page" is built.

So one solution should be : if the insert is too long, the next part is forgotten, and add to the insert of what user expected to be the right page, but after the skip to this page.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, the part after (each) split is essentially back into the \insert and appears in the insert box on the next page just as if it had been a new `\insert` with the remaining text.

Comment: ok, thank, I understand better. I will complete my first question

Comment: So I have just done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't think I understand the question, but this is an answer to some question, hopefully this one.

[image]

Here the insert is restricted to odd pages and if it is split it is held over on the even page and re-inserted so the rest of it appears on the next odd page.

Comment: Ok, this can be a method to manage long notes, but it's not what we  want.

To see the actual result, you could run this file https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/blob/issue17/issue17.tex

But what we want is something like maieulrouquette.perso.sfr.fr/bilingue.pdf : the left note is continued in the right side. But with the actual method of // typessetting in eledpar, it's not possible

Comment: so, I have ask. Why is not possible to add § in comment to answer ?

Comment: what you show in the pdf is just a normal split footnote as would occur in latex or plain tex, if the ledpar output routine is stopping that then the question is really about the details of that package not tex-core, sorry but I don't know that package well enough to disentangle its output routine during working hours:-)

Comment: yes, of course. The problem is inside the managing of the // typesseting in ledpar, which I tried to explain in this question. 

It's explained in more detail into the documentation of eledpar.

Comment: I thank I understood the problem in this composition, and why I doesn't have the standard comportement.

Comment: And I can't see any way to change the ledpar system to of // pages typesetting.

Comment: That is why I would like to change the "what happen to the too larger insert" to manage with the method of // typesetting of eledpar

Comment: But I understand you can't do it in your working hour. And I'm sorry, but it's not very obvious for me to explain it in english

Comment: Inded, as my need is to debug ledmac/ledpar, which is written with TeX command, I need to ask question about TeX...